# Calculate best interval between peaks

Tags: optimization

I have a vector of values with zeros and some rare positive value (corresponding to the peaks in the hist)

```
[    0.      0.    112.4   451.2     0.    287.5     0.      0.     74.2
     0.    114.      0.      9.2   660.5     0.      0.      0.     76.2
    18.9     0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.   5648.4
     0.      0.      0.     82.8     0.      0.      0.      0.      0.
     0.      0.   5585.8     0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      9.6
     0.      0.     94.2   267.2     0.      0.   2053.      0.    253.5
     0.      9.5     0.    309.6     0.      0.      0.    751.5    56.2
     0.      0.      0.      0. ]
```

[image]

I'd like to calculate the **most adequate interval** between those peaks.

**The most adequate interval** is the one that passes as near as possible from the highest peaks and do not passe as much as possible from 0 values.

Visually it seams that the adequate interval is **12**

I guess it's an optimisation problem but I don't know how to modelize it.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have a discrete x-axis there is a finite number of candidates for intervals. You could calculate the means of every 9th element, every 10th element, every 12th element and so on, each with the different possible starting points and then decide for the interval and the starting point with the highest mean of values.

If the vector of values is long and there are too many values, than Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT) might be a better answer, but for the given example, brute force should do.

Edit: I have tried it with the given sample data and found the following table:

```
lag start    mean
 1     1 16925.4
 1     0 16925.4
 2     1 11978.7
 4     3 11618.5
 6     3 11486.6
12     3 11402.8
 5     2  8452.9
 5     4  7311.3
 7     6  6790.8
13     1  6308.9
```

The top values are achieved with intervals of 1, 2, 4, 6 and 12. The interval of twelve with starting point at 3 hit the two highest values and misses the 3rd, 4th and 5th highest value. That is why the smaller Intervalls perform so well: 12 Looks like the answer but is not neccessarily the best answer. If you want to include "almost hit" values, you will have to define, what an "almost hit" is and how it should be weighed.

I will add my R code. It is probably easy to adapt to usefull definitions of "almost hit".

```
data <- c(0,0,112.4,451.2,0,287.5,0,0,74.2,0,114, 0,9.2,660.5,0,0,0,
          76.2,18.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5648.4,0,0,0,82.8,0,0, 0,0,0, 0, 0,
          5585.8, 0,0,0,0,0,9.6,0,0,94.2,267.2,0,0,2053,0,253.5,0,9.5,
          0,309.6, 0,0, 0,751.5,56.2,0, 0,0,0)

#possible lags between 1 and 20
pl <- 1:20
results <- data.frame()

calculatemean <- function(lag, start){
  sum(data[seq(from=start, to=67, by=lag)])
}

for(lag in pl){
  for(start in 1:(lag-1))
    results <- rbind(results, c(lag, start, calculatemean(lag, start)), make.row.names=FALSE)
}
names(results)=c("lag","start","mean")

print(head(results[order(results[[3]],decreasing = TRUE),],15))
```

Comment: If I do this, the best answer for each case will be **1**

Comment: If you do it with 1, than a lot of zeros will go into the calculation of the mean. Why should that lead to the highest mean?

Comment: Because the interval can be slightly different between two high peaks, and we are looking maybe for the mean of them. an interval that minimizes the error (distance to a highest peak).  So calculate the mean with a fixed interval will probably not give a good result, as it can pass over a high peak that is juste at i+1 or i-1.

Comment: I have added results and code in the answer above. If you want to include "almost hits" as i+1 and i-1 you will have to define exacly, how near an almost hit may be and how to weigh "almost hits" as opposed to "true hits". Once a precise definition is given, brute force testing still seems to be appropriate. In my code above, I defined a function `calculatemean`. That would be a suitable place to add the new information.

Comment: I've found something better for my case, see my answer above

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good error function to minimize.

Result

```
interval: 12 -> error: 1410866.7
interval: 11 -> error: 1431395.8
interval: 9 -> error: 1438693.8
interval: 10 -> error: 1487976.6
interval: 7 -> error: 1497223.6
interval: 8 -> error: 1500589.7
interval: 13 -> error: 1526180.9
interval: 6 -> error: 1612798.8
interval: 14 -> error: 1683577.1
interval: 15 -> error: 1718685.4
interval: 5 -> error: 1765212.1
interval: 4 -> error: 2084023.5
interval: 3 -> error: 2610722.7
interval: 2 -> error: 3846174.7
interval: 1 -> error: 7518148.7
```

python code:

```
data = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 112.4, 451.2, 0.0, 287.5, 0.0, 0.0, 74.2, 0.0, 114.0, 0.0, 9.2, 660.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 76.2,
            18.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5648.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 82.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            5585.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0, 0.0, 94.2, 267.2, 0.0, 0.0, 2053.0, 0.0, 253.5, 0.0, 9.5,
            0.0, 309.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 751.5, 56.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

indexes = data.nonzero()[0]
lag_errors = {}

for lag in range(1, 20 + 1):
    error = 0
    for pos, i in enumerate(indexes):
        for j in indexes[pos + 1:]:

            k = (j - i) // lag
            distance_error = (j-i) % lag
            if distance_error > lag / 2:
                distance_error = lag - distance_error

            error += (distance_error + k) * (data[i] + data[j])

    lag_errors[lag] = error

for k, v in sorted(lag_errors.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print "interval: %s -> error: %s" % (k, v)
```